# Bootstrap 3 Table column same width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the same width to all columns,
Is there a proper way for Bootstrap?

```
                <a href="produkte.html">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th> # analog Eingänge</th>
                                <th> # I/Os</th>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that it is much better to use Bootstrap's rows and cells in your case.

Answer (score 12):

you have to set this style to your table

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use cells and/or rows?
If you don't know then add this code(also learn it, it can be useful)

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```